# How to solve array push problem in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i have a **Two fields** **1. allowances** which is contain this data

```
{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900"}
```

and another one **2. house rent** which is contain this data

```
2550.00
```

**now i want to get a result in third column like this**

```
{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900","house_rent":"2550.00"}
```

so far i tried this

```
$allowances=json_decode($salary->allowances);
$house_rent = array('House Rent' => $salary->house_rent);
$allowances_logs=array_push($allowances,$house_rent);
$salary->allowances_logs = $allowances_logs;
```

but it gives me following error`"array_push() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given"`. Help me achieve this result. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Look into Eloquent's `$casts`, so you don't have to JSON encode/decode the database value - Laravel will handle that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, add `true` as second argument to `json_decode()`, and you will retrieve the results as an array instead of an object.

Second, with the two arrays, do:

```php
$merged = array_merge($arr1, $arr2);
```

Answer (score 0):

`true` Add second argument in `json_decode()`, so you can see below example

```
$mainArr = json_decode('{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900"}',true);
$house_rent = array('House Rent' => 2550.00);
$printArr = array_merge($mainArr, $house_rent);
print_r(json_encode($printArr));
```

Output

```
{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900","House Rent":2550}
```

Answer (score 0):

First convert your json to array. 
You can do this with **json_decode** php function.

**json_decode** function convert your json to object or associative array.
First argument on this function is the json string being decoded.
When is second argument are TRUE, returned objects will be converted into associative arrays.

```
$testJson = '{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900"}';
$testArr = json_decode($testJson, true);

Output - Array ( [medical] => 600 [transport] => 350 [food] => 900 )
```

Now you can add new item to your array.

```
$testArr['house_rent'] = '2550.00';
```

Your array now look like this.

```
Array ([medical] => 600 [transport] => 350 [food] => 900 [house_rent] => 2500.00)
```

At the end you convert your array to json. For this you can use php **json_encode** function.

```
$testJson = json_encode($testArr);
```

Full Example

```
$testJson = '{"medical":"600","transport":"350","food":"900"}';
$testArr = json_decode($testJson, true);

$testArr['house_rent'] = '2500.00';

$testJson = json_encode($testArr);
echo $testJson;
```